# how to remove a Negative using a txt editing batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need a little help with this 
I recently asked a different question on this same script 
Now I have my scripted working for me and found a new issue 
Here is my script

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: Significant part of string

set "params1="okhg": "
set "params2="tfed": "
set "params3="pkna": "
set "params4=txt": ""

@For %%G In ("%~dp0Preparing") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0Ready") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 rem calculate new destination directory
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
  rem %%j now has sequence number
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   for %%x in (%params1%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs1 %%j
   for %%x in (%params2%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs2 %%j
   for %%x in (%params3%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs3 %%j
   for %%x in (%params4%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs4 %%j
   echo(!line!
  )
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs1
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params1%%%s=%params1%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs1
set "line=!line:%params1%=%params1%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs2
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params2%%%s=%params2%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs2
set "line=!line:%params2%=%params2%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs3
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params3%%%s=%params3%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs3
set "line=!line:%params3%=%params3%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs4
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params4%%%s=%params4%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs3
set "line=!line:%params4%=%params4%CITY%1!"
GOTO :eof
```

This is how it works

```
ORIGNAL FOLDER
+ ----- FOLDER 1
--------+ --(100) Filename.txt
-------------+ -- "okhg": 452587"
-------------+ -- "tfed": 6541"
-------------+ -- "pkna": -58452"
-------------+ -- "txt": ""

RESULTS FOLDER
+ ----- FOLDER 1
--------+ --(100) Filename.txt
-------------+ -- "okhg": 100"
-------------+ -- "tfed": 100"
-------------+ -- "pkna": 100-58452"
-------------+ -- "txt": "CITY100"
```

The issue I am coming across with is that this line has a negative

```
"pkna": -58452"
```

I have tested different ways to make the scripts remove the negative

if I leave it like this, I get this result

```
set "params3="pkna": "
  "pkna": 100-58452"
```

if I do this, I get this result

```
set "params3="pkna": -"
      "pkna": -100"
```

what I am looking for is  this

```
"pkna": 100"
```

Thank you

Comment: directly after the line `:subs3` put a line `SET "line=%line:-=%"` which should remove all `-` characters from the line.

Comment: @Magoo - Thank you very much - Didn't think about setting a new line with the negative, and I love that it still works even if it doesn't have a negative so I will add this to every Sub, for just incase a negative appears in the future

Comment: you could always follow `set "line=%%b"` with `set "line=!line:-=!"`, I suppose...

Comment: @Magoo - so what would happen here if I did that `IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!"`

Comment: These two lines do not appear to be right: ```@For %%G In ("%~dp0Preparing") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"``` and ```@For %%G In ("%~dp0Ready") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"```. Given your replacement, that would look like this: ```SET "newdest=!C:\Users\Hot-Topic\Documents\Project1\Preparing\SubDir\:C:\Users\Hot-Topic\Documents\Project1\Preparing=C:\Users\Hot-Topic\Documents\Project1\Ready!"```. Are you sure that such a replacement is actually working okay for you?

Comment: @Compo - Yes, everything does work correctly paths for `Source` and `Destination` work perfectly fine - Quick question, I don't want to over ask, but I'm looking to updating this script one more time, should I ask here or should I ask a new question - the update I'm working on is a type of Find and Replace action along with the sequence editing that it already does, I have a total of 6 codes and 3 require a sequence and 3 require a solid number, like if I need 10 for three codes and the other 3 codes are coded based on `(?)` these

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to add a content replacement, where it doesn't use a the sequence number, Now I have copied my script and I edited this section `FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (`  - this section here is my sequence `("%%~nxq")`  I did this `("10")` to remove the sequence and add the number I needed, and it works great, but I am trying to put both scripts together in one, so now I have 2 scripts, trying to make it 1 script

Comment: I did it - in a pretty ugly way, but it works, I now can edit all 6 codes with one script

Comment: @Hot-Topic, how about you use the answer area, and submit your solution for everyone else to see and understand. Not only could you eventually mark your own solution as the accepted answer, others may be able to offer better, _(less ugly)_, alternatives.

Comment: @Compo- Oh ok great

Comment: @Compo - I have shared my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

The question has been updated with an answer.

The code will "code" multiple row/lines in to a text file using its prefix name, or with a "more direct" coding.

If you do know a way to clean up the code feel free to post an answer to do so., I would like to leave a script that I can continue to add more codes if needed

Thank you for all the hard work you'll provide us with to make our scripts better

```
@ECHO Off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd /d "%~dp0"
:: Significant part of string

set "params1="okhg": "
set "params2="tfed": "
set "params3="pkna": "
set "params4=txt": ""

@For %%G In ("%~dp0Preparing") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0Ready") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"

FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (
 rem calculate new destination directory
 SET "newdest=%%~dpq"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:%sourcedir%=%destdir%!"
 SET "newdest=!newdest:~0,-1!"
 MD "!newdest!" 2>nul

(
 rem this will take the data in the filename enclosed in (!)
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%j IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
 rem this will replace any random codes found after : with 10
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%k IN ("10") DO (
 rem this will add any wording after this : and will take data enclosed in (!)
 FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=()" %%l IN ("%%~nxq") DO (
  rem %%j %%k %%l now has sequence number or pattern
  for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%%q"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   rem in order to make each code work I gave them there own ::Substitute
   for %%x in (%params1%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs1 %%j
   for %%x in (%params2%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs2 %%j
   for %%x in (%params3%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs3 %%k
   for %%x in (%params4%) do if defined line IF "%%b" neq "!line:%%x=!" CALL :subs4 %%l
   echo(!line!
    )
   )
  )
 )
)>"!newdest!\%%~nxq" 

)
GOTO :eof

:: substitute
:subs1
SET "line=%line:-=%"
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params1%%%s=%params1%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs1
set "line=!line:%params1%=%params1%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs2
SET "line=%line:-=%"
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params2%%%s=%params2%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs2
set "line=!line:%params2%=%params2%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs3
SET "line=%line:-=%"
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params3%%%s=%params3%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs3
set "line=!line:%params3%=%params3%%1!"
GOTO :eof

:subs4
SET "line=%line:-=%"
SET "original=%line%"
FOR /L %%s IN (0,1,9) DO set "line=!line:%params4%%%s=%params4%!"
IF "%original%" neq "%line%" goto subs3
set "line=!line:%params4%=%params4%City%1!"
GOTO :eof
```